# MS Access 2010: Cannot find RunCode action

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I cannot for the life of me find RunCode macro action in MS Access 2010. It should be in the drop down, or in the tree to the right of the macro editor. Where is it?

Comment: Are you in a web or client database? If the former, it's not going to be there, as you can't run arbitrary code in a web database.

Comment: What was it? To help others, you need to explain the answer to the question.

Comment: FWIW, there's also another possible cause of this. From http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=151373 : "As it is considered an 'unsafe' action you need to enable those type of macros. Go up to the Ribbon and select SHOW ALL ACTIONS."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some macro actions can't be used in a web database. This office.com article lists them: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/web-compatibility-check-macro-errors-HA010386888.aspx

Also, some macro actions are considered less safe and are hidden by default. To show them, with the macro open in design view, on the **Design** tab, in the **Show/Hide** group, click **Show All Actions**.

Comment: Make sure your project is not a web database!

Answer (score 0):

I created a new db and found it, between RestoreWindow and RunDataMacro.